# In MySQL database how do you give condtion to attribute

Tags: mysql, database, data-modeling

I've been working on a university project where I have to create many tables and their attributes. I've made a table called customers with attribute's of customer_name, .... etc and one of the attribute is age. I've assigned TINYINT UNSIGNED Datatype to it. How do I add a condition to age? I have to check if the age entered by the user is greater than 18?

Comment: you should add a where condition ` WHERE age > 18 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a check constraint https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Or create a trigger [enter link description here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)
and signal an error [enter link description here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html)

Or test on INSERT , where ...

But age may not be the best thing to store - next year customer will be a year older but ae column won't reflect that

Comment: Ohh I see that's how I use triggers and Constraints. I'll try implementing those

Answer (score -1):

You cannot. MySQL will accept anything matches the schema.
but you can define a cursor which anytime that something inserted to the Table, it will check it and delete if it doesn't have the condition.

Comment: 'MySQL will accept anything matches the schema;' - partially true please look at my answer.